How to Set a Whitelist of Domains for a Segment JavaScript source WriteKey to Prevent Misuse?
I am working on a project that utilizes a JavaScript source writeKey to send data to Segment Analytics. Since this code runs on the client-side, I'm concerned about the potential for the writeKey to be extracted and misused by third parties on unauthorized domains.
Is there a way to configure a whitelist of domains through any settings in the analytics service, which would only allow my writeKey to be used from specific, authorized domains I designate?
I've looked through the segment documentation and security options, and they recommend generate a new key If there are any unusual behavior associated with the write key.
What is the impact of exposing the sources write keys?
Has anyone implemented a similar solution or has recommendations on how to better secure the write key for client-side scenarios?
Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
